# Handle null values in MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, null, nullable

i have 50 properties in model name 'student' and im trying to set all properties NULL values to "" to prevent error messages in case of NULL.is there c# method that can do that?

thank you for your help.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Are your properties all string ? Please show us the code for your model

Comment: But a wild guess would be: I think your only way to actually do this is through reflection and that'd be dirty. You're better off to simple give your model a constructor that can pre-set all your properties.

Comment: And a last note: *error* message in case of `null` are **errors**, not warning. To me you shouldn't just use trick like that to dodge the problem.

Comment: this sounds like a bad workaround. what errors are you getting and where from? Perhaps you have fields in your database which are not nullable? In that case, either make them nullable, if it's ok for those fields to be null. If not, then use some validation in your code to ensure that any user input into this table is not permitted when the fields are null. If you are talking about some other scenario, you'll have to explain it more. Your question is too vague to be certain what to tell you.

Answer (score 2):

You could initialize each property in your model (pretty simple with search/replace):

```
public string PropertyName { get; set; } = "";
```

However, I would question whether it is better to handle your NULL scenarios. It is pretty simple (`model.PropertyName?.Method()`).

Answer (score 0):

Use a backing field for each.

In the get for each property, coalesce via `return this.field ?? string.Empty;`

Answer (score 0):

Change the model to have fail safe check, as below.Will below work for you?

```
public class Student
    {
        private string _Name;

        public string Name
        {
            get => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_Name) ? string.Empty : _Name;
            set => _Name = value;
        }
        //todo: rest of properties
    }
```